# Safari padded container doesn't respect aspect-ratio

Tags: html, css, layout, safari, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to make a padded div container respect a certain aspect-ratio. As soon as I'm placing an element inside, it works well in Chrome but in Safari the container's aspect-ratio is not respected.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="element" />
</div>

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 10vw;
  padding: 20px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.element {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: royalblue;
}
```

I've made a Codepen to illustrate my problem: https://codepen.io/MaxOlliv/pen/LYreNNO

Here, I'd like the dark container to be a square (aspect-ratio of 1). It works in Chrome, but in Safari it's not a square.
Thank's for your help !

Comment: What version of Safari are you on, and on IOS or....?

Comment: I'm on Safari 15.4

Comment: I am seeing the same problem on 15.4 It seems any type of padding setting (even rubbish ones like padding: garbage) make the child pick up a height related to the window height not respecting the parent's aspect ratio. aspect-ratio was introduced to Safari in version 15+ so I wonder if this is an associated bug - but I can't find anything to suggest it is known as yet.